How do I vlookup the results of another vlookup in the same table
I'm trying to write a formula in a single cell which will tell me for each group in column 2 if there is a dependency linked in any row.
I can do this using two new colunms but can't work out how to merge them into one formula.
1st step:
=INDEX(B2:C2,MATCH("y",C2,0),1)

2nd step:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,E:E,1,0)),"n","y")

This gives the desired result but I need these formula merged together or if there is a better way to do this please let me know.


What version are you using? How is your check column done? (is it the result of the 2nd step?); there's probably a dynamic array formula, but only if your excel version supports it.

The simplest way I can think of is COUNTIFS:
=IF(
    COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C,"y")>0,
    "y",
    "n"
)


Id recommend avoiding whole column references if you can for efficiency... a table would appear to be a good idea in this instance.
EDIT - Add a note about VLOOKUP
I always recommend avoiding VLOOKUP. It should NEVER be used as far as I am concerned. INDEX/MATCH does exactly the same thing and more. It is more versatile, less fragile, and is faster.
In newer Excel versions, VLOOKUP has essentially been deprecated and replaced by the much more efficient XLOOKUP, however I still prefer INDEX/MATCH as it won't break if opened using an older version of Excel.

I don't even think you need >0 since any integer greater than zero is considered TRUE.

@P.b Thanks for pointing that out, you are correct. However, I always like to specify things like that. It's just my personal preference.

There are many ways to get desired result. One of them:
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,FILTER($B$2:$B$13,C$2:C$13="y"),0)),"n","y")


To spill whole result without dragging formula down:
=MAP(B2:B13,LAMBDA(a,IF(ISNA(MATCH(a,FILTER($B$2:$B$13,C$2:C$13="y"),0)),"n","y")))

